# Cross compiling cppzmq for arm cannot find sodium.h

Tags: c++, c, cmake, cross-compiling, meson-build

I have a  C++ application and I need to cross compile it for armv7. It needs 3 libraries:

- [cppzmq](https://github.com/zeromq/cppzmq)
- [Eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page)
- [nlohmann/json](https://github.com/nlohmann/json)

#### What I have

- A raspberry compute module 3+ with Debian 9 Buster
- Manjaro Linux (or windows I guess)

```bash
$ uname -a
Linux user 5.15.71-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Sep 28 11:24:27 UTC 2022 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

- A project set up with CLion and Meson by me following the basic [cross compiling tutorial](https://mesonbuild.com/Cross-compilation.html) (see below for files content)

  - arm-none-linux-gnueabihf toolchain
  - meson txt file for setting up the toolchain
  - meson.build file
  - meson .wrap files for [easier dependencies management](https://mesonbuild.com/Wrap-dependency-system-manual.html)

#### What is my issue

This is my first time doing cross compiling or working with C in general, I know I'm really near the solution but I'm wasting a little too much time on this.

- I'm able to compile Eigen and Json
- I added catch2 and libzmq to solve some issues and I can compile these too
- libobsd and libsodium are compiled but not picked up by cppzmq

I think I need to pass the compiled libobsd and libsodium as libraries to cppzmq but I'm not sure. Error log cleaned up:

```bash
Executing subproject cppzmq 

cppzmq| Project name: cppzmq
cppzmq| Project version: 4.8.1
cppzmq| C++ compiler for the host machine: /usr/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf-g++ (gcc 10.3.1 "arm-none-linux-gnueabihf-g++ (GNU Toolchain for the A-profile Architecture 10.3-2021.07 (arm-10.29)) 10.3.1 20210621")
cppzmq| C++ linker for the host machine: /usr/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf-g++ ld.bfd 10.3-2021
cppzmq| C++ compiler for the build machine: c++ (gcc 12.2.0 "c++ (GCC) 12.2.0")
cppzmq| C++ linker for the build machine: c++ ld.bfd 2.39.0
cppzmq| Dependency libzmq from subproject subprojects/zeromq-4.3.4 found: YES undefined
cppzmq| Dependency threads found: YES unknown (cached)
cppzmq| Dependency catch2 from subproject subprojects/Catch2-3.1.0 found: YES 3.1.0
cppzmq| Build targets in project: 149
cppzmq| Subproject cppzmq finished.

meson 0.0.1

  Subprojects
    catch2     : YES
    cppzmq     : YES
    eigen      : YES
    json       : YES
    libobsd    : YES
    libzmq     : YES 2 warnings

  User defined options
    Cross files: /my_path/meson/raspberry-cm3+.txt
    backend    : ninja

Found ninja-1.11.1 at /usr/bin/ninja
Cleaning... 107 files. 
[1/270] Compiling C++ object subprojects/zeromq-4.3.4/libobjects.a.p/src_msg.cpp.o
FAILED: subprojects/zeromq-4.3.4/libobjects.a.p/src_msg.cpp.o 
/usr/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -Isubprojects/zeromq-4.3.4/libobjects.a.p -Isubprojects/zeromq-4.3.4 -I../srcdir/subprojects/zeromq-4.3.4 -I../srcdir/subprojects/zeromq-4.3.4/include -Isubprojects/zeromq-4.3.4/__CMake_build -I../srcdir/subprojects/zeromq-4.3.4/__CMake_build -fdiagnostics-color=always -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Wall -Winvalid-pch -Wnon-virtual-dtor -std=gnu++11 -O0 -g -fPIC -Wno-tautological-constant-compare -O3 -DNDEBUG -DZMQ_CUSTOM_PLATFORM_HPP -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_REENTRANT -D_THREAD_SAFE -MD -MQ subprojects/zeromq-4.3.4/libobjects.a.p/src_msg.cpp.o -MF subprojects/zeromq-4.3.4/libobjects.a.p/src_msg.cpp.o.d -o subprojects/zeromq-4.3.4/libobjects.a.p/src_msg.cpp.o -c ../srcdir/subprojects/zeromq-4.3.4/src/msg.cpp
In file included from ../srcdir/subprojects/zeromq-4.3.4/src/msg.cpp:31:
../srcdir/subprojects/zeromq-4.3.4/src/compat.hpp:42:10: fatal error: bsd/string.h: No such file or directory
   42 | #include <bsd/string.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
[2/270] Compiling C++ object subprojects/zeromq-4.3.4/libobjects.a.p/src_ipc_address.cpp.o
FAILED: subprojects/zeromq-4.3.4/libobjects.a.p/src_ipc_address.cpp.o 
/usr/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -Isubprojects/zeromq-4.3.4/libobjects.a.p -Isubprojects/zeromq-4.3.4 -I../srcdir/subprojects/zeromq-4.3.4 -I../srcdir/subprojects/zeromq-4.3.4/include -Isubprojects/zeromq-4.3.4/__CMake_build -I../srcdir/subprojects/zeromq-4.3.4/__CMake_build -fdiagnostics-color=always -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Wall -Winvalid-pch -Wnon-virtual-dtor -std=gnu++11 -O0 -g -fPIC -Wno-tautological-constant-compare -O3 -DNDEBUG -DZMQ_CUSTOM_PLATFORM_HPP -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_REENTRANT -D_THREAD_SAFE -MD -MQ subprojects/zeromq-4.3.4/libobjects.a.p/src_ipc_address.cpp.o -MF subprojects/zeromq-4.3.4/libobjects.a.p/src_ipc_address.cpp.o.d -o subprojects/zeromq-4.3.4/libobjects.a.p/src_ipc_address.cpp.o -c ../srcdir/subprojects/zeromq-4.3.4/src/ipc_address.cpp
In file included from ../srcdir/subprojects/zeromq-4.3.4/src/ipc_address.cpp:31:
../srcdir/subprojects/zeromq-4.3.4/src/compat.hpp:42:10: fatal error: bsd/string.h: No such file or directory
   42 | #include <bsd/string.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
[3/270] Compiling C++ object subprojects/zeromq-4.3.4/libobjects.a.p/src_curve_mechanism_base.cpp.o
FAILED: subprojects/zeromq-4.3.4/libobjects.a.p/src_curve_mechanism_base.cpp.o 
/usr/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -Isubprojects/zeromq-4.3.4/libobjects.a.p -Isubprojects/zeromq-4.3.4 -I../srcdir/subprojects/zeromq-4.3.4 -I../srcdir/subprojects/zeromq-4.3.4/include -Isubprojects/zeromq-4.3.4/__CMake_build -I../srcdir/subprojects/zeromq-4.3.4/__CMake_build -fdiagnostics-color=always -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Wall -Winvalid-pch -Wnon-virtual-dtor -std=gnu++11 -O0 -g -fPIC -Wno-tautological-constant-compare -O3 -DNDEBUG -DZMQ_CUSTOM_PLATFORM_HPP -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_REENTRANT -D_THREAD_SAFE -MD -MQ subprojects/zeromq-4.3.4/libobjects.a.p/src_curve_mechanism_base.cpp.o -MF subprojects/zeromq-4.3.4/libobjects.a.p/src_curve_mechanism_base.cpp.o.d -o subprojects/zeromq-4.3.4/libobjects.a.p/src_curve_mechanism_base.cpp.o -c ../srcdir/subprojects/zeromq-4.3.4/src/curve_mechanism_base.cpp
In file included from ../srcdir/subprojects/zeromq-4.3.4/src/curve_mechanism_base.cpp:32:
../srcdir/subprojects/zeromq-4.3.4/src/curve_mechanism_base.hpp:38:10: fatal error: sodium.h: No such file or directory
   38 | #include "sodium.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

#### Files Details

**raspberry-cm3+.txt** to set up the cross compiling

```ini
[binaries]
c = '/usr/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf-gcc'
cpp = '/usr/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf-g++'
ar = '/usr/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf-ar'
strip = '/usr/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf-strip'

[host_machine]
system = 'linux'
cpu_family = 'arm'
cpu = 'armv7hl'
endian = 'little'
```

**meson.build** to set up the project

```ini
project('meson', 'cpp', version : '0.0.1')

cpp = meson.get_compiler('cpp')
os = target_machine.system()

cmake = import('cmake')


dep_eigen = subproject('eigen').get_variable('eigen_dep')

lib_zmq = cmake.subproject('libzmq')
dep_zmq = lib_zmq.dependency ('libzmq')

# lib_libsodium = cmake.subproject('libsodium')
# dep_libsodium = lib_libsodium.dependency ('sodium')

# lib_libsodium = cpp.find_library('libsodium', required: false)
#   if lib_libsodium.found()
#     dep_sqlitecpp = lib_libsodium
#    endif

dep_catch = subproject('catch2').get_variable('catch2_dep')
dep_libobsd = subproject('libobsd').get_variable('libobsd_dep')

if cpp.has_header('zmq.hpp')
    # cppzmq is a header-only dependency, so if we already have the
    # header in place, we don't need to actually change anything
    dep_cppzmq = [] #declare_dependency()
else
    dep_cppzmq = subproject('cppzmq').get_variable('cppzmq_dep')
endif

if cpp.has_header('nlohmann/json.hpp')
    dep_json = [] #declare_dependency()
else
    dep_json = subproject('json').get_variable('nlohmann_json_dep')
endif

deps = [
dep_eigen,
# dep_libsodium,
dep_libobsd,
dep_catch,
  dep_zmq,
  dep_cppzmq,
  dep_json
]

executable(
'demo',
'main.cpp',
dependencies :deps
)
```

**Wrap Files**

- catch2, cppzmq, eigen, libobsd and json are the default ones from the [meson wrap repository](https://mesonbuild.com/Wrapdb-projects.html)
- libsodium.wrap (custom repo to use cmake)

```ini
[wrap-git]
directory = libsodium-1.0.18
url = https://github.com/robinlinden/libsodium-cmake.git
revision = master
depth = 1
clone-recursive = true

[provide]
libsodium = libsodium_dep
sodium = sodium_dep
```

- libzmq.wrap

```ini
[wrap-file]
directory = zeromq-4.3.4
source_url = https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq/releases/download/v4.3.4/zeromq-4.3.4.tar.gz
source_filename = zeromq-4.3.4.tar.gz
source_hash = c593001a89f5a85dd2ddf564805deb860e02471171b3f204944857336295c3e5

[provide]
libzmq = libzmq_dep
```

#### Notes

- I don't mind switching build tools to CMake for example
- there is another toolchain on the AUR repository I don't know if it could change anything (trying right now)
- ???
- profit

Updated information: I updated the cmake a little but I've kinda put the project on standby, anyway here is the CMakeList.txt, I added some caching

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(my_project_name)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
include(./cmake/CPM.cmake)
CPMAddPackage(
        GITHUB_REPOSITORY gabime/spdlog
        VERSION 1.11.0
)
CPMAddPackage(
        NAME nlohmann_json
        VERSION 3.11.2
        # the git repo is incredibly large, so we download the archived include directory
        URL https://github.com/nlohmann/json/releases/download/v3.11.2/include.zip
        URL_HASH SHA256=e5c7a9f49a16814be27e4ed0ee900ecd0092bfb7dbfca65b5a421b774dccaaed
)
if (nlohmann_json_ADDED)
    add_library(nlohmann_json INTERFACE IMPORTED)
    target_include_directories(nlohmann_json INTERFACE ${nlohmann_json_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
endif()
set(BUILD_TESTING OFF)
CPMAddPackage(
        NAME Eigen
        GIT_TAG 3.4.0
        GITLAB_REPOSITORY libeigen/eigen
        DOWNLOAD_ONLY YES
)
if(Eigen_ADDED)
    add_library(Eigen INTERFACE IMPORTED)
    target_include_directories(Eigen INTERFACE ${Eigen_SOURCE_DIR})
endif()
CPMAddPackage(
        NAME zeromq
        GITHUB_REPOSITORY zeromq/libzmq
        VERSION 4.3.4
)
CPMAddPackage(
        NAME cppzmq
        GITHUB_REPOSITORY zeromq/cppzmq
        VERSION 4.9.0
)
add_executable(my_binary MySource1.cpp MySource2.cpp)
target_link_libraries(
        my_binary
        PRIVATE nlohmann_json
        cppzmq
        spdlog
        Eigen
    )
```

and this is the CPM.cmake

```
set(CPM_DOWNLOAD_VERSION 0.36.0)
if(CPM_SOURCE_CACHE)
    set(CPM_DOWNLOAD_LOCATION "${CPM_SOURCE_CACHE}/cpm/CPM_${CPM_DOWNLOAD_VERSION}.cmake")
elseif(DEFINED ENV{CPM_SOURCE_CACHE})
    set(CPM_DOWNLOAD_LOCATION "$ENV{CPM_SOURCE_CACHE}/cpm/CPM_${CPM_DOWNLOAD_VERSION}.cmake")
else()
    set(CPM_DOWNLOAD_LOCATION "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/cmake/CPM_${CPM_DOWNLOAD_VERSION}.cmake")
endif()
# Expand relative path. This is important if the provided path contains a tilde (~)
get_filename_component(CPM_DOWNLOAD_LOCATION ${CPM_DOWNLOAD_LOCATION} ABSOLUTE)
if(NOT (EXISTS ${CPM_DOWNLOAD_LOCATION}))
    message(STATUS "Downloading CPM.cmake to ${CPM_DOWNLOAD_LOCATION}")
    file(DOWNLOAD
            https://github.com/cpm-cmake/CPM.cmake/releases/download/v${CPM_DOWNLOAD_VERSION}/CPM.cmake
            ${CPM_DOWNLOAD_LOCATION}
            )
endif()
include(${CPM_DOWNLOAD_LOCATION})
```

Comment: Just to clarify: `libsodium` is a (optional) dependency of `libzmq` (aka `zeromq`), and `libzmq` is a dependency of `cppzmq`.

Comment: Yes, I think I may be building zeromq without libsodium, so I'd need to include it and pass it to cppzmq. I think I also need to pass libbsd the same way to cppzmq

Comment: I "solved" it by using intellij remote ssh and compiling directly on the raspberry while still coding on my computer. I used cmake fetchcontent to easily get and compile all the needed libraries, if someone wants to see the Cmakelist just ask

Comment: Hello, I am interested to see the CmakeList. Thank you

Comment: I added the latest version I used, I stopped working on that so I cannot remember any other details at the moment